# При использования flipper, как указать первый экран?

Tags: java, android

В OnCreate прописываю:

```
flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
int layouts[] = new int[]{R.layout.scr1, R.layout.scr2, R.layout.scr3, R.layout.scr4};
for (int layout : layouts) flipper.addView(inflater.inflate(layout, null));
```

В приложении "пролистываю", например, на scr3, потом ориентация экрана меняется и я опять в scr1.

Текущее положение (номер scr) я знаю как сохранить, но как потом применить? Т.е. как написать, чтобы загрузился scr3 при создании экрана?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flipper.setDisplayedChild(savedIndex);
```

Comment: Komdosh, Подскажите еще, пожалуйста, а как отловить смену экрана (получить текущий scr)? Просто я делал нажатием на кнопки "вперед,назад", и не учел, что пользователь может переключить экраны непосредственным касанием.

Comment: ловить `OnTouchEvent` и обрабатывать его

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже нашел.